# Squaring a polar equation, extraneous solutions?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

If I have the equation $y=x$, it provides a graph of a single line.  However, if I square both sides, I have $y^2=x^2$ whose graph is both $y=x$ and $y=-x$.  Should the same be true for polar equations and graphs instead of rectangular?  For instance, say I have $$r=\frac{4}{1+\sin \theta}$$ and want to write it as a rectangular equation.  If I first graph it by hand, I can see it looks like it is producing a downward opening parabola.  And, in fact, if I find its rectangular equation, it is $y=-\frac{x^2}{8}+2$.  However, in obtaining that equation, I had at one point $r=4-y$.  I then squared both sides to obtain $r^2$ on the left so I could substitute $r^2=x^2+y^2$.  Why didn't I create extraneous solutions?  I know I did not because the polar graph of $r=\frac{4}{1+\sin \theta}$ and rectangular graph of $y=-\frac{x^2}{8}+2$ match up.  Thanks!

Comment: Good question, how doubling up in this case does not show, right?

Answer (score 0):

By squaring you get another curve in polar coordinates. By substituting  $ r\rightarrow -r$ we get $ r=-f(\theta) $  anti-symmetric curve to the original $ r = f(\theta)$  (and vice-versa) formed around the origin.

[image]

EDIT1:

During the process of squaring you introduce a negative sign unwittingly.
When you decided to square you were agreeing to see another changed sign in front of the radical sign, $r$ can be either $+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ or$\,-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$

Although you took

$ r=\dfrac{4}{1+\sin \theta} $

but the problem was you were not *a priori* prepared to take

$ r=\dfrac{-4}{1+\sin \theta} $

which is the parabola hat is facing upwards.

Alternately if you square first time

$$ (4-r)^2 = y^2 $$

$$ 16- 8 r + r^2=16- 8 r + x^2+y^2 = y^2$$

$$ r = 2 + \dfrac{x^2}{8}$$

And again square for a second time

$$ x^2+y^2 = 4+ \dfrac{x^4}{64}+  \dfrac{x^2}{2}$$

and simplify

$$[ y- (2- \dfrac{x^2}{8})] \cdot [y+ (2+ \dfrac{x^2}{8})] =0 $$

which appears as a product of the original and "extraneous" parabolas.

It is interesting even a conic in canonical form ( focus at origin)

$ \dfrac {p}{r}= (1 - e \cos \theta )$ or $\quad p = r -  e \, x $

may not produce a contour plot for $  p = -r -  e \, x $ as a default option in some CAS.

Comment: I agree that is what I think would happen.  But that doesn't happen for my particular example. Why not?